# Youtube embedded video diplay blank screen

Tags: html, iframe

I just copied the link to embed a youtube video in my localhost site.

```
<div class="video">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/sewZ2a-LBcQ?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

but only a blank screen is displayed in the `div` container.

What is wrong? Is it perhaps different in lamp sites?

Update 1:

It seems there is some issue with localhost (lamp), as it is running in http://jsfiddle.net.

Update 2:

This is embarrassing but the video now is displaying. Don't know why it did not before.

Comment: It seems this code is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/nmgtjsh0/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the protocol instead of "//" in the src. https://www.youtube.com/embed/sewZ2a-LBcQ?feature=player_detailpage. If you test it local it will try to resolve the url as "file://www.youtube.com/embed/sewZ2a-LBcQ?feature=player_detailpage".

Comment: Yes, @user3786513, I tried that, but blank screen persists.